# Installing Certain PPAs

Tags: terminal

I'm following my own article: [Making a Wireless Hotspot](http://www.gymforgeeks.com/topic/356870-make-ubuntu-a-wireless-hotspot-not-ad-hoc/)

When I put in

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd
```

I get the message

> Cannot access PPA
>   (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd) to get
>   PPA information, please check your internet connection.

I use Cylon Linux, which uses the updates from Ubuntu 12.04, basically. I'm using Ethernet.

After doing it and responding to an answer, I get

```
Address already in use
                                                                         [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript dnsmasq, action "start" failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to a quick Google Search the correct PPA should be:

```
ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

instead of

```
ppa:nilarimogard/webupd
```

Comment: However, now I get " Address already in use
                                                                         [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript dnsmasq, action "start" failed."